# Please help me understand the methods underlying two proofs about the diagonals of a parallelogram.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

First my book presents me with an example that shows that if the diagonals of a
quadrilateral bisect then the quadrilateral is a parallelogram.

Then my book presents me this problem:

> Demonstrate the reciprocal property of the one in the example, or: in
>   a parallelogram the diagonals bisect.

This is the example:

> [image]
>
> We want to demonstrate that if $W$ is the central point of $[Z_1Z_3]$
>    and $[Z_2Z_4]$, then, $[Z_1Z_2Z_3Z_4]$ is a parallelogram. Considering that the quadrilateral is in the complex plane and that the complex numbers $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$, $z_4$ and $w$
>
> $$w=\frac{z_1+z_3}{2}\land
>  w=\frac{z_2+z_4}{2}\Rightarrow\frac{z_1+z_3}{2}=\frac{z_2+z_4}{2}
>  \Leftrightarrow z_1+z_3=z_2+z_4\\ \Leftrightarrow z_1-z_2 = z_4-z_3$$
>
> It can be concluded that $\vec{Z_2Z_1}=\vec{Z_3Z_4}$ so that
>    $[Z_1Z_2]$ and $[Z_3Z_4]$ are paralell.
>
> In conclusion: the quadrilateral is a parallelogram

I have several questions about this:

1. What are $z_1-z_2$ and  $z_4-z_3$? Are they w?
2. What is a "reciprocal property"?
3. I think the answer to the problem is $\frac{z_1+z_3}{2}=\frac{z_2+z_4}{2}$, but this seems too obvious. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456093/diagonals-of-a-parallelogram-bisect-each-other)

Comment: Possibly, but the OP has some questions about the method that need answering and those may make an answer more useful to others in the future.

Comment: @DavidK I made a 3 points list specifying my questions. How do I make this more clear?

Comment: OK, I retracted my close vote. I did this even before you improved the title of the question, but I think the new title does make the question even clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What are $z_1-z_2$ and $z_4-z_3$?

The point $Z_1$ (a geometrical object) can be presented by the complex number $z_1$ in this way:

Let $(x_1,y_1)$ be the coordinates of $Z_1$.

Let $z_1=x_1+iy_1$

The vector $\vec{Z_1Z_2}$ can be represented by the complex number $z_2-z_1=(x_2-x_1)+i(y_2-y_1)$

The midpoint of $Z_1Z_2$ can be represented by the complex number ${z_1+z_2} \over 2$

You should be able to convince yourself of these two statements by trying a few numerical examples.

For example, consider $A(2,7)$ and $B(10,3)$.

The vector joining them is $8-4i$.

Their midpoint is $6+5j$ or $M(6,5)$

The proof you have starts with the property that $W$ is the midpoint of $Z_1Z_3$ and is also the midpoint of $Z_2Z_4$. That means that $w$ satisfies both of these equations:

$w={z_1+z_3\over 2}$ and $w={z_2+z_4\over 2}$

The proof then goes on to show that this leads to the property:

$z_1-z_2=z_4-z_3$

This property means that the two vectors $\vec{Z_2Z_1}$ and $\vec{Z_3Z_4}$ are equal, which means that the sides are parallel and equal in length: a parallelogram.

2. What is a 'reciprocal property'?

This is asking you to prove the opposite. Starting from the point where you know that a quadrilateral is a parallelogram, can you use similar methods to prove that the diagonals must bisect each other?

3. I think the answer to the problem is $\frac{z_1+z_3}{2}=\frac{z_2+z_4}{2}$, but this seems too obvious.

A little bit. All we have to start with is that the quadrilateral is a parallelogram. So we know that $z_1-z_2=z_4-z_3 \Rightarrow z_1+z_3=z_2+z_4$

Let $W_1$ be the midpoint of $Z_1Z_3$, so that $w_1=\frac{z_1+z_3}{2}$.

Let $W_2$ be the midpoint of $Z_2Z_4$, so that $w_2=\frac{z_2+z_4}{2}$.

But $z_1+z_3=z_2+z_4 \Rightarrow w_2=\frac{z_1+z_3}{2}=w_1$

So the midpoint of $Z_1Z_3$ is also the midpoint of $Z_2Z_4$. In other words, they bisect each other.

Therefore if a quadrilateral is a parallelogram, its diagonals wll bisect each other.

Comment: But why does it work to subtract the points?

Comment: Vector rules: $\vec{AB}=\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}$

Comment: So, to answer the problem I'd just have to do $z_1-z_2=z_4-z_3 \Leftrightarrow z_1+z_3=z_2+z_4 \Leftrightarrow \frac{ z_1+z_3}{2} = \frac{z_2+z_4}{2}$?

Comment: Also you said that the midpoint could be represented by $z_1+z_2$. Do you mean $\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, fixed that